# strange behavior with stl containers and pointers

Tags: c++, stl

I don't understand why the following does not work:

```
queue<int*> q;

int counter = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    int a[1] = {counter};
    q.push(a);
    counter++;
}

while (!q.empty()) {
    int *top = q.front();
    q.pop();

    cout << top[0] << endl;
}
```

It should print out: 1 2 3, but instead 3 3 3 is printed out. This is because the pointers in the queue are all the same after each run through the loop. Why does that happen?

Comment: From what source are you learning C++ that you would even conceive of doing such a thing?

Comment: http://images.slashdot.org/articles/08/08/14/142201-1-thumblg.png

Comment: As Abraham Lincoln once said, you can't believe everything you read on the Internet!

Comment: This is my favorite thing today.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are storing pointers to local variables and using those pointers after the local variables they point to have gone out of scope.

In other words: you are invoking [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Result: It should not print out "1 2 3". It doesn't have to do anything and is allowed to do whatever it likes. "3 3 3" seems reasonable to me, as it is also allowed to crash.

Answer (score 4):

```
int a[1] = {counter};
q.push(a);
```

Not correct. It invokes undefined behvaiour, as `a` doesn't exist outside the curly braces  (the for-loop block). Even if it were well-defined, your code has another problem, all the items in `queue` is same, as `a` (the same memory) gets used repeatedly in the loop.

The solution is this:

```
int *a = new int[1];
a[0] = counter;
q.push(a);
```

If you do so, then you've to deallocate the memory yourself, of course.

---

But I'm wondering if every item in `queue` is just one `int`,then why not use the following:

```
queue<int> q;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
{
  q.push(counter);
  counter++;
}
```

Or if you really want array, then why not use `std::queue<std::vector<int> >` as :

```
std::queue<std::vector<int> > q;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
{
  std::vector<int> v;
  v.push_back(counter);
  q.push(v); //dont worry - a copy of the vector is being pushed!
  counter++;
}
```

In this way, you don't have to deal with raw pointers. You don't have to allocate or deallocate memory yourself which in my opinion is a safe approach!

Comment: so if i do it this way and variable a goes out of scope (say i pass q to some other function), does q.pop() free up the heap memory originally pointed to by a?

Comment: @Jeff: No. You've to deallocate it yourself.

Comment: I used int* in the example to generalize to arrays instead of just ints

Comment: @Jeff Chen No, you have to make q a `queue<auto_ptr<int>>` (assuming you're using `new int(counter)`) to achieve that.

Comment: @Jeff: You can also use `std::vector<int>` instead of raw pointers.

Comment: @elusive: Yes, in C++03. In C++0x, its okay.

Comment: @Nawaz: I know, but we do not know what is being used here. `> >` is safe :)

Comment: @Nawaz: the vector approach makes a lot of sense...I'm still getting comfortable with thinking in C++ instead of falling back to C

Comment: @Jeff: Yes, it happens. When you come from one language to another, then it usually happens that you write code in the second language, but the style, the accent remains the same as before, that of the former language.

Comment: @elusive yeah, typo on my part, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

You have undefined behavior, since your declaration of `a` goes out of scope at the end of the loop where you're pushing it into the queue.

What's probably happening is that the memory location of `a` gets reused each time through, but there are absolutely no guarantees. You might get a different output next time you run it, or you might get a crash, or demons may fly out of your nostrils.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using pointers to integers, the following code does what you want:

```
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::queue<int*> q;

  int counter = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    int* a = new int;
    *a = counter;
    q.push(a);
    counter++;
  }

  while (!q.empty()) {
    int *top = q.front();
    q.pop();

    std::cout << *top << std::endl;
    delete top;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Neil it does, but I didn't want to change OP's code any more than necessary so that the issue would be more clear.